# A form to mysql query

Tags: mysql

People, I need a form with textarea(name size) to mysqli_query $ebur

Soory, my english is bad :(

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("ipaddress","user","passw","account");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Falha ao receber moedas, informa o administrador com o codigo 445ebmds. " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `account` SET `coins`='2000' WHERE ($ebur)");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: no question just to observe how nice is the code :)

Comment: People, I need a form with text area to that mysql query field $ebur

Soory, my english is bad :(

Comment: Oh. I forgot. something something deprecation use PDO link here..or is that just mysql_* not mysqli?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

mi_page.php

```
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['ebur']))
    {
        $ebur = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ebur']);
    $con=mysqli_connect("ipaddress","user","passw","account");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Falha ao receber moedas, informa o administrador com o codigo 445ebmds. " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE account SET coins='2000' WHERE mi_field_on_the_table_account = '$ebur'");

    mysqli_close($con);
    }
    ?>

    <form method="post" action ="mi_page.php">
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="ebur" name="ebur">

    </textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
    </form>
```

All in the same file.

Saludos from Chile ;)

Comment: I can use only the form in another page?

Comment: Yes, you can use only the form in another page...example my_form.html and the php code on my_page.php, fijate que concuerde la pagina del codigo php en el action del form ;)

Comment: Robert, why i don't have a submit button? :(